# Using partition key in function Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, partitioning

We have a partioned table in our Oracle database using this syntaxe:

```
...
PARTITION BY RANGE(saledate)
(PARTITION sal99q1 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01-APR-1999', 'DD-MON-YYYY')),
PARTITION sal99q2 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01-JUL-1999', 'DD-MON-YYYY')),
...
```

We usually use partition key in select statement like this:

```
Select * from table where saledate >= trunc(sysdate-3) and saledate < trunc(sysdate-2)
```

To have same result using less code, I usually use this query instead :

```
Select * from table where trunc(saledate) = trunc(sysdate-3)
```

My question is, by using partition key in a function, in this case trunc(), do we loose partioning performance ?

Comment: It likely depends on your data set. You should compare explain plans for the two queries.

Comment: I would guess that you would lose performance with the second method.  You should check the query plan to see if this is the case.

Comment: @Politank-Z Thank you friend, please comment on my answer to make sure that im right.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thank you friend, please comment on my answer to make sure that im right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misinterpreting the plan shown by Toad (in your answer). For the two queries that shows, respectively:

```
Partition #: 2 Partitions determined by key values
```

and

```
Partition #: 1 Partitions accessed #1 - #17
```

The first query is accessing only the partitions it needs, based on the key value, which is the date; so it only has to do a full scan of the partition(s) that could contain your date.

The second query has to access all partitions because you are manipulating the key value with a function, meaning you are no longer really using the partition key. The key is `saledate`, not `trunc(saledate)`. This is similar to what happens when you use a function on an indexed column; the index is no longer used in that case, and the partition key is no longer used here. And as you seem to suspect from your question, yes, you do lose efficiency.

You can also see that the cardinality has been guessed as 50 because of the function call, instead of the stats-provided value of 4966.

You can see the same thing from a dummy table using `dbms_xplan`; from your first query:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
| Id  | Operation                 | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |  
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT          |      |  4996 | 39968 |    14   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |  
|*  1 |  FILTER                   |      |       |       |            |          |       |       |  
|   2 |   PARTITION RANGE ITERATOR|      |  4996 | 39968 |    14   (0)| 00:00:01 |   KEY |   KEY |  
|*  3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL      | T42  |  4996 | 39968 |    14   (0)| 00:00:01 |   KEY |   KEY |  
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):                                                 
---------------------------------------------------                                                 

   1 - filter(TRUNC(SYSDATE@!-3)<TRUNC(SYSDATE@!-2))                                                
   3 - filter("SALEDATE">=TRUNC(SYSDATE@!-3) AND "SALEDATE"<TRUNC(SYSDATE@!-2))
```

And from your second query:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------        
| Id  | Operation           | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |        
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------        
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT    |      |    50 |   400 |    14   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |        
|   1 |  PARTITION RANGE ALL|      |    50 |   400 |    14   (0)| 00:00:01 |     1 |    17 |        
|*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL | T42  |    50 |   400 |    14   (0)| 00:00:01 |     1 |    17 |        
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------        

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):                                                 
---------------------------------------------------                                                 

   2 - filter(TRUNC(INTERNAL_FUNCTION("SALEDATE"))=TRUNC(SYSDATE@!-3))
```

Notice the pstart/pstop values and the cardinality in each query.

Your first query is going to be more efficient because it can use the partition key to be selective about which partitions it does a full scan of, while the second cannot and has to scan them all.